# Change product link in woocommerce on content-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change link that appear as http://localhost/product/happy-ninja/
to http://localhost/product/happy-ninja?product=$product_id
and the code in the content-product.php look like this(line 44):

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink($product_id); ?>">
```

how to add the part `?product=`
Thanks for your help

Comment: To what end? You could just as easily tell WooCommerce to use `localhost?product=$product_id` as the permalink.

Comment: Could you please tell me how exactly of doing it?

Comment: You can [edit your site's permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen) in the admin. Settings>Permalinks. However, I apologize as I assumed that `?product=$product_id` was an option that you could select from the permalinks settings since you can display posts/pages like that. However it *isn't* a default option and would probably require custom code.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the permalink with the [post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_link) filter

I have not tested it but this code might works:

```
function append_query_string( $url, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
        $url = add_query_arg( 'product', $post->ID, $url );
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 3 );
```